# Multithreading for multiple functions inside a threaded function in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python program which does multithreading for a function like this. This code snippet starts a thread for each account supplied as a list element. [Irrelevant snippets of code are omitted for simplicity.]

```
def main():
    for account in dict_list:
    threads = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=f_action, args=(account,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Now the function `f_action(account)` is something like this.

```
def f_action(account):
    #Does some stuff
    sub1f_action()
    sub2f_action(a,b)
    sub3f_action(c)
    sub4f_action()
```

My questions:

1. How can I multithread sub-functions so that they would execute
   parallel?
2. The function `f_action()` would be running for each account in a thread. Is it OK or recommended to have sub-threads
   from that?

Comment: Have you tried it?, https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @wwii Tried the first threading option? Yes, I did and that works fine. What I don't know is how to do threading for four different functions.

Comment: @wwii I think I am pretty sure what I want here is multithreading - not multiprocessing as the functions I call are not processor intensive.

Comment: Threads don't run in parallel in Python. Use multiprocessing - take a look at the docs I linked to.

Comment: @wwii I guess that's fine for this program as these are more of I/O bound programs. Not expecting a significant time advantage here. Can you help me how multithreading for four functions as given can be syntactically achieved?

Comment: The same way you did it in `main()`, except iterate over the functions and pass each function as an argument to the `target` parameter?

Comment: At times I sound too stupid to myself when I hear someone speak wisdom :D I just realized how simple it was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157628/discussion-between-hax-and-wwii).